# compare two columns of df and making new column if there values are increasing then to write increasing in other column and same for decreasing

Tags: r

I have a data set as given below

```
name   col1   col2
  a    10.3   10.9
  b    11     15 
  c    20     7.2
  d    6.2    6.2
  e    5.3    5.4
  f    4.5    4.0
```

i want to compare col1 and col2 of my df and i want to make another column in which while comparing col1 and col2 values if value of col2 is increasing from col1 then i want to enter increasing next to them in my column there and if they are decreasing then i want to write decreasing and no changes if they are same

and i want my output like this

```
name   col1   col2   col3
  a    10.3   10.9   increasing 
  b    11     15     increasing
  c    20     7.2    decreasing 
  d    6.2    6.2    no change
  e    5.3    5.4    increasing
  f    4.5    4.0    decreasing
```

Comment: I think you need nested `ifelse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
 df %>% 
   mutate(Col3=ifelse(col2 == col1, 
                       "no change",
                             ifelse(col2 > col1,
                                    "increasing","decreasing")))
```

Or using `case_when` as suggested by @akrun :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Col3 = case_when(col1 == col2 ~ "no change" ,
                          col2 > col1 ~ "Increasing",
                          TRUE ~ "decreasing"))
```

Result:

```
 name col1 col2       Col3
1    a 10.3 10.9 increasing
2    b 11.0 15.0 increasing
3    c 20.0  7.2 decreasing
4    d  6.2  6.2  no change
5    e  5.3  5.4 increasing
6    f  4.5  4.0 decreasing
```

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), col1 = c(10.3, 
11, 20, 6.2, 5.3, 4.5), col2 = c(10.9, 15, 7.2, 6.2, 5.4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can subtract `col1` by `col2` and then use `sign` to assign values

```
df$col3 <- c("decreasing", "no change", "increasing")[sign(df$col1 - df$col2) + 2]
df

#  name col1 col2       col3
#1    a 10.3 10.9 decreasing
#2    b 11.0 15.0 decreasing
#3    c 20.0  7.2 increasing
#4    d  6.2  6.2  no change
#5    e  5.3  5.4 decreasing
#6    f  4.5  4.0 increasing
```

Or using `dplyr` we can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(col3 = case_when(col1 == col2 ~"no change",
                          col1 > col2 ~"increasing", 
                          TRUE ~"decreasing"))
```

Comment: I edited to add akrun 's suggested `case_when` before seeing your answer. Will just leave it as is.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Can you plz tell me how we can do this while applying group by

Comment: @xyz You can add `group_by` there. I don't think anything would change if we apply this by group though.

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
 df$col3<-with(df, ifelse(col1>col2,"decreasing",
ifelse(col1<col2,"increasing",ifelse(col1==col2,"no change","error"))))
```

Data:

```
 df<-read.table(text="
        name   col1   col2
        a    10.3   10.9
        b    11     15 
        c    20     7.2
        d    6.2    6.2
        e    5.3    5.4
        f    4.5    4.0
        ",header=TRUE)
```